# Get static final field of Type T of a class

Tags: java, class, static, final

I have following three class definitions:

```
public class Bounds {
    public Bounds (int a, int b, int c, int d) { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}

public class A {
    public static final Bounds BOUNDS = new Bounds(1, 2, 3, 4);

    public A () { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}

public class B extends A {
    public static final Bounds BOUNDS = new Bounds(5, 6, 7, 8);

    public B () { super(); /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}
```

Then I have a method looking like this:

```
public void Foo (Class<? extends A> cls) {
    cls.getField("BOUNDS").get(null); // Doesn't work
}
```

When I try to call `Foo(B.class)`, I get an error saying "incompatible types" while highlighting the `get(null)`. My question is: **How can I get the value of** `BOUNDS` **using the** `Class`**-class?**

*(I don't want to know that I can use* `A` *instead of* `Class<? extends A>`*)*

**EDIT:** If I use `getInt(null)` for static final integers or `getDouble(null)` for static final doubles, it works.

Comment: Please be more specific about the error message. Particularly, does it say which two types were incompatible?

Comment: Not really. This is a school project, so we all have to work with Greenfoot. The only error Greenfoot returns is "incompatible types".

Comment: If your IDE doesn't even give you complete error messages, then it's junk. Use a better IDE, or javac directly. Your code works fine here, so I guess that you have multiple B classes, and that you're using the wrong one. Check your imports.

Comment: Do you have any piece of code that you're not showing us? The signature for the `public Object get(Object obj)` is Object. And if you're assigning the result to something or using it somehow somewhere, you might get this error. Because I just tried your code in Oracle JDK and there is no error. I used the code you have shown as is.

Comment: I can write down the exact code. But since this is a school project, there are many files and many classes. In the `get(Object obj)` I don't use the result of something, I use `null`. Then I want to assign the return value to a variable of type `Bounds`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to:

```
public <T extends A> void Foo (Class<T> cls) {
    System.out.println(cls.getField("BOUNDS").get(null));
}
```

Test for this method:

```
class Bounds {
    int a, b, c, d;
    public Bounds (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bounds [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + ", d=" + d + "]";
    }
}

//classes A and B were kept as defined in OP's code

public class Test {

    public static <T extends A> void Foo (Class<T> cls) {
        try {
            System.out.println(cls.getField("BOUNDS").get(null));
        } catch(Exception lazyToHandle) {}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo(B.class);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Bounds [a=5, b=6, c=7, d=8]
```

Comment: No. It still says "incompatible types". The error appears on the `get(null)`.

Comment: @Cubinator73 make sure to wrap `cls.get` call using a `try/catch` statement.

Comment: The problem is, Greenfoot doesn't compile anything until it believes that there is no error. I tried wrapping this part into a try/catch statement, but it still says "incompatible types". (I don't say that your solution is wrong, but in Greenfoot it doesn't work)

Comment: Then use another IDE.

Comment: We can't use another IDE. We are forced by our teacher to use Greenfoot

Comment: It's great that your teacher wants to teach you Java, and it's wise of him to use a tool that simplifies things a little, but it looks like he didn't choose the right one. If it does not compile correct Java code and it shows such lacking error messages, then it is not going to do any good. Switching to a regular IDE (or even trying the command line if you're up to the task) would be the right move.